# How to change title in listings?

Tags: latex, listings

I have a question about the [`listings` package](//ctan.org/pkg/listings). Do you know how to change it to get a title like this "Algorithm ## Title" rather than the casual "Listing ## Title" in the title line?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Put these lines to preamble (the preamble is everything from the start of the LaTeX source file until the `\begin{document}` command):

```
\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Algorithm}
\renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{Algorithms}
```

The first changes the caption name for listings. The second — the header name for the list of listings which is printed by the `\lstlistoflistings` command. You would also probably want to modify the text in `autoref`s:

```
\def\lstlistingautorefname{Alg.}
```

Then when you're referring to a particular listing, e. g. `For details see \autoref{sec2:bubblesort}.` it is written as "For details see Alg. 2.1."

Comment: When I make `Figure` the number starts from 1 even if there is previous figures